# ImportError: Failed to import msrest.authentication

Tags: python, azure

I have Python 2.7.9 with azure-2.0.0rc4 and msrest-0.4.0.  My code failed to import from msrest.authentication.  I checked the two files from azure and msrest packages, and could not find any issues.

Appreciate any advice and direction.

John

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getCredential.py", line 1, in <module>
    from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/common/credentials.py", line 25, in <module>
    raise ImportError("You need to install 'msrest' to use this feature")
ImportError: You need to install 'msrest' to use this feature
```

Comment: how did you install them? with pip?

Comment: yes,  pip install --pre azure

Comment: what does --pre do?   Also, did you install msrest the same way?

Comment: It was recommended to use --pre option to include pre-release and development versions. By default, pip only finds stable versions.  I did not use --pre when installing msrest.

Comment: I can reproduce your issue at the first time I install the pre azure pakcage. But then it works fine after several times install the virtual env and the package. Also you can try to manually install `msrest` first, then install pre azure pakcage.

Comment: Thanks, Gary.   What do you mean by "install the virtual env"?   I installed msrest manually.  But will try to uninstall both packages, and then install msrest first.   John

Comment: I found the issue.   When I sudo pip install,  read permission was not set for the others group.  Once I fixed that, the issue went away.   Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug with the `pip install --pre azure`.

Running this command afterwards installs the necessary packages:

```
pip install msrestazure
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. When I sudo pip install, read permission was not set for the others group. Once I fixed that, the issue went away.